# Batch adding an image to an audio file to create an mp4

Tags: audio, video, images

I Have two folders one: is filled with 100 images and the other is filled with 100 audio files. They are in order, as in image 1 goes with audio 1.

I'm using windows and the naming scheme I would change to suit the programming.

Is there a way to, all in one go, overlay the image over the related audio to create an mp4 file?
So that I now have 100 video files with the image over the audio.

It would save lots of time in the long run.

Comment: You should state what operating system you’re using (and what audio/video-related software you already have).  What have you already learned from your research of this issue?

Comment: What is the naming scheme, exatly? `Video 1` <-> `Audio 1`, or `Movie 1.video-extension` <-> `Movie 1.audio-extension`, or...?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this as I have been unable to get the naming scheme you have been using.

You can use Python OpenCV to accomplish the audio-less video part. Then, combining audio can probably using Python's libraries as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python .

Prerequisite:
Use `subprocess` or `os.system()` to call system functions through Python.
Call the process and determine the length of each audio through a batch file which would store the result in Excel/CSV.

Creation of video from image.
Pseudo-code is as follows:

```
numberOfAudio=100;
imageFrequency=33;

for(i=0; i<numberOfAudio; i++){
lengthOfAudioI = ReadFromExcel(i);

//j in milliseconds
for(j=0; j<lengthOfAudioI; j = j + 1000/imageFrequency){
OpenCVvideoWrite(readImage(ImageLocation), imageFrequency);
//https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html
}
}
```

Finally, use a software like Windows Movie Maker/Camtasia Studio or online/open-source video editors to combine the audio and video streams.

Note: Naming convention or DIR command can be used for `imageLocation`.